# MongoDB Install Simple Test Ops Manager java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on startup

Tags: mongodb

just installed a test evaluation of MongoDB Ops Manager and get an error on startup of the Backup HTTP server:

```
Migrate MMS data
   Running migrations...[  OK  ]
Start MMS server
   Instance 0 starting..........[  OK  ]
Start Backup HTTP Server
   Instance 0 starting.......[FAILED]

2015-05-07T14:00:32.107+0000 [main] gid  ERROR ServerMain:199 - Cannot start bslurp server [FATAL-EXITING] - instance: 0  - msg: unable to create new native thread
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I appear to have plenty of memory

```
[root@krh60621 ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15951       4588      11362          0        364       2021
```

and I upped the max processes to unlimited to see if that would help....

```
[root@krh60621 ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127421
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 94000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

[root@krh60621 ~]# ps -eLF| grep -c java
593

[root@krh60621 ~]# ps -eLF| wc -l
1031
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this exception is very misleading. You need to change the ulimit on the linux machine to fix this issue:

You can check the ulimits with:

```
ulimits -a
```

and change the limit with:

```
ulimit -n 64000
```

And try to restart the service with the new limits.

Source: [docs.MongoDB.org](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/)